# Social Networking APIs for PHP

Tags: php, api, social-networking

Good Morning SO Campers,

I'm interested in developing a social networking site.  It will be run on a Linux dedicated server and must be written in PHP.
The site functionality will be a cross between FaceBook, Myspace and Yahoo.  Specifically, the site needs to offer:

- The ability for users to obtain a free email address.
- Instant Messaging
- RSS Feeds for Weather, News Etc.
- Member pages where they can send/receive emails, maintain their own profile etc.

Instead of building this solution from scratch, I'm seeking input as to the types of APIs, plugins, modules that are available to cobble this solution together.

Thanks, in adavnce, for your help and insight.

Comment: Does Elgg have the ability to host free email accounts on a site?  I'm thinking of a plugin like Smartermail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Elgg](http://elgg.org).

Elgg is highly extensible and has a good array of plugins already written for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also consider CMS systems, which have Social Networking components/extensions.
E.g. Joomla has [JoomSocial](http://www.jomsocial.com/). I am also sure that most of this functionality may
be constructed in [Drupal](http://drupal.org) using its numerous modules.

Answer (score 0):

See also [SocialEngine](http://www.socialengine.net/)

Comment: I'm working with SE at the minute and there is literally no documentation :( How have you faired using this? and where do you find all your documentation?

Comment: The link just doesn't have any documentation of how to develop new modules and the general structure of the Engine api etc its only really fit for users wanting to do stuff through the website interface and not the code behind :(

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in another answer you could look at Jomsocial which is very good. If you are interested in a free extension to Joomla then you could also look at [Communtity Builder](http://www.joomlapolis.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered Buddy Press?